# MySql Join Type Weirdness (using "ALL" instead of "eq_ref")

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I'm building a flattening query for some data and I got to this foreign key that causes the query suddenly goes from running in 0.031s to running in 2.460s. I analyzed the query and the join is being done as an `ALL` join with the extra `Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)` instead of an `eq_ref` join.

In an effort to figure out what's going on I made a copy of the two tables and stripped them down to the bare minimum. The table definitions are:

```
CREATE TABLE `zz_submission` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rcId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_rcId` (`rcId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `zz_rc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`zz_rc` has 5 rows with names. `zz_submission` has 5 rows with valid id's from RC.

When I run this query the "type" for table `r` is `all`:

```
explain SELECT
    s.ID,
    r.name
FROM zz_submission s
    LEFT JOIN zz_rc r ON s.rcId = r.id
;
```

[image: Image 1]

When I run this query the "type" for table `r` is `eq_ref`:

```
explain SELECT
    s.ID,
    r.id
FROM zz_submission s
    LEFT JOIN zz_rc r ON s.rcId = r.id
;
```

[image: Image 2]

Why would selecting the ID vs Name column in the join table affect the join type? I tested this on my original query and it switches back to running in 0.031s again.

What can I do to make the query use the eq_ref join here?

Comment: You are not showing the explain output, total rowcounts. Your question lacks detail

Comment: You stripped them down too much.  For **5** rows, it is faster to scan the table than to use any index.

Comment: Sorry I added the explain output.

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems to read the entire `s` table, then read much or all of the `r` table, correct?

`Using join buffer` means that it loads up the needed data from `r` into buffer.  This can be done in one fast sweep over the index (the PK, in your case).  Then, lookups can be done in RAM, without hitting `r` further. -- This explains `ALL` instead of `eq_ref`.

The first `SELECT` needs both `id` and `name`; the second needs only `id`.  Based on the datatypes (and no knowledge by me, or the by the optimizer, of the bulkiness of that `VARCHAR`), one would guess that [id,name] would be a lot bigger than just [id].

The "join buffer" is of limited size -- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'join_buffer_size';`.  So it might hold all of [id] but not be big enough for [id,name].

Do you really have `names` anywhere near 255 characters long?  Your example may be a good one for why 255 should not be everyone's default.

`eq_ref` means that it will do a reasonably efficient lookup in `r`.  But that is likely to be slower than `Using join buffer`.

`Block Nested Loop` means, roughly:  Loop through `s`, reaching into `r` for each row.

Each connection might allocate a "join buffer", so don't make it bigger than 1% of RAM.

Comment: Correct. S is my main table and I'm getting all of the rows from that. I'm joining in the FK from R to get a status name. I don't understand why the join type and execution time vary so drastically just based on which column I select from the joined table.

Comment: See 2nd paragraph for "why ALL, not eq_ref".